# Is there any work, api, publication, or example of providing a SPARQL query engine ontop of an OSLC web service?

Tags: rdf, sparql

I am interested in putting a [SPARQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARQL) query engine in front of an [OSLC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Services_for_Lifecycle_Collaboration) based web service.  I do not have access to change the web service and I want to query it as part of a federated query.

Does anyone know of any publication, or API or other example that describes such a setup?

If none exists I suppose I will have to proceed along the lines of [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/264558653_Linked_Biomedical_Dataspace_Lessons_Learned_integrating_Data_for_Drug_Discovery).

Answer (score 0):

There has been some work by some, [such as IBM, to build a SPARQL index](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/ratiengilifemana) by leveraging the [Tracked Resource Specification (TRS)](http://open-services.net/wiki/core/TrackedResourceSet-2.0/) to keep the index current.  Though, it could be possible to leverage a similar model and using [OSLC's query capability](http://open-services.net/bin/view/Main/OSLCCoreSpecQuery) to build such an index and keep it current.  As you say, it depends a lot on what tool(s) you are trying to connect to and what support they expose.  At the simplest level, you could just treat like Linked Data and crawl the links and leveraging HTTP caching controls to minimize requests.